# How can I convert a string to UTF-16LE and then to Base64?

Tags: vb.net, string, base64, utf-16le

I'm throwing together a program as a refresher for VB.net, and I figured I might as well make it do something that I have to do a lot anyways: Convert an input string into UTF-16LE and then into Base64.

Now, in PHP, I can do it like this:

```
<?php
$UTF8_String = "example string"; 
$UTF16_String = mb_convert_encoding($UTF8_String,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
$base64_encoded = base64_encode($UTF16_String);
echo $base64_encoded;
```

Sweet and simple.

...but in vb.net, I can't figure out how to get the string from

`Dim strInput = inputBox.Text`

convert it to UTF-16LE (it has to be UTF-16LE), and then the convert the resulting string to Base64.

Thank you!

Edit:  Gserg and Steven's code both works equally well, and it helps to seeing two methods of converting text: One with specifiable encoding and one with Unicode. Steven's answer is more complete at this time, so I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-16LE in .NET, unfortunately, is simply called "Unicode" (code page ID 1200).  So, the proper encoding object to use for UTF-16LE is `Encoding.Unicode`.  The first step is to get a byte array for the UTF-16LE representation of the string, like this:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputBox.Text)
```

Then, you can convert those bytes into a Base64 string by using the `Convert` class, like this:

```
Dim base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
```

The `Encoding` class has public properties for several of the most common encoding objects (e.g. `Unicode`, `UTF8`, `UTF7`).  If, in the future, however, you need to use a less common encoding object, you can get it by using the `Encoding.GetEncoding` method.  That method takes either a code page ID or name.  The list of supported code pages can be found in the table on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim b = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16LE").GetBytes(inputBox.Text)
Dim base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did have to include the `System.Text` part for the first line, for some reason the `Imports System.Text` doesn't work. 

In other words, you just made my day nicer. Thank you!